# Open external WebView links in browser

Tags: android, webview

I know this has been asked multiple times but I went through all the answers and I just cant get it to work. Im trying to make a simple webview app that handles external links in native browser.

```
package com.example.app;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView webview;
    private long backPressedTime;

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (webview.canGoBack()) {
            webview.goBack();
        } else {
            if (backPressedTime + 2000 > System.currentTimeMillis()) {
                super.onBackPressed();
                return;
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Press back again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            backPressedTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webview.setOverScrollMode(WebView.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
        webview.loadUrl("https://www.myurl.com");
    }

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override URL loading with following code. If you want to handle URL loading yourself return `true`. If the URL should be opend in the WebView, return `false`.

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // Insert logic here
    }
}
```

If you just want to open external links you can use following code. In case the opened URL starts with your domain's base URL, `false` is returned and the URL is opened in the WebView. Otherwise the `ACTION_VIEW` intent is used to open the URL in the browser and true is returned.

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // Abort if no URL
        if (url == null || !(url.startsWith("http://") ||
                url.startsWith("https://"))) {
            return false;
        }

        // Abort if internal URL
        if (url.startsWith("http://www.myurl.com") || 
                url.startsWith("https://www.myurl.com")) {
            return false;
        }

        // Open external URL in browser
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
        return true;
    }
});
```

Notice: You have to handle "http://..." and "https://...". Because the method might get called for both.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I just don't understand how to implement this code into what i already have. This is way over my head

Comment: I have reworked my answer. You have to add the code to your onCreate method, before `webview.loadUrl(...);`.